# Angular 2 and typescript, cannot set property of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

i´m having problem with setting the reviews,
This is part of angular 2 project.
The line this.reviews = targ gives me
TypeError: Cannot set property 'reviews' of undefined
The targ seems to exist as i can print it into console succesfully.
Any ideas why this is happening?

```
import { ReviewService } from '../review.service';
import { Review } from '../review/review.component'
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import {  OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'review-list',
  templateUrl: './review-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./review-list.component.css'],
  providers: [ReviewService] //for the injector to be able to inject ReviewerService
})

export class ReviewListComponent implements OnInit {
   public reviews: Review[];

  constructor(private reviewService: ReviewService) {
    this.reviews = [] ;
  }


  initializeReviews(): void {
     this.reviewService.getReviews().then(
        this.set    
     ).catch(function(reason){
        console.log(reason);
     });

  }  



  set(targ):void {
    console.log(targ);
    this.reviews = targ;

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.initializeReviews();   
    //this.reviews = this.reviewService.get();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

When method references are passed, `this` doesn't keep pointing to the current class instance by default. Use `.bind(this)` or arrow functions to ensure `.this` points to the current class instance:

```
  initializeReviews(): void {
     this.reviewService.getReviews().then(
        this.set.bind(this) // << add `.bind(this) or
        // (val) => this.set(val)    
     ).catch(function(reason){
        console.log(reason);
     });

  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are losing the `this` context if you pass the `method` like that to the `promise`. You should either use an anonymous function wrapper, or bind the `this`context

```
initializeReviews(): void {
   this.reviewService.getReviews().then((response) => {
       this.set(response);
   })
   .catch((reason) => {
    console.log(reason);
   });
}
```

or

```
this.reviewService.getReviews().then(this.set.bind(this))
```

Also never use the `function` keyword inside a `TypeScript` class. This will also cause the `this` context to get lost.

Comment: sorry. I had a confusion with the bind method. Thanks.